# How can I get Stored Procedure return value in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored Procedure that do some operation and return 1 or 0 as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UserCheckUsername11
(
    @Username nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF Exists(SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE username =@Username) 
    return 1
ELSE
    return 0
END
```

and in C# i want to get this returned value i try `ExcuteScalar` but it didn't return any value ( i know if i replace `return 0` with `Select 0` `ExcuteScalar` will catach it .. but is it any way that allow me to get returned value with replace `return` with `select` ?

NOTE : I don't want to user stored procedure output parameter also

Comment: Can you post your C# code that accesses this stored procedure?

Comment: it's just sqlcommand that of type stored procedure that excute the SP

Comment: thanks, but if use microsoft SQLHelper version 2.0 ?? how can i do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In essence you have to define a parameter with "direction" return value.

You can find some examples here: [Using ADO.NET with SQL Server](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/3/) and here: [Get the Return Value from an SQL Stored Procedure](http://snipplr.com/view/2373/get-the-return-value-from-an-sql-stored-procedure/).

Here comes the relevant part from the first link cited:

> To get the value of a RETURN
>   statement, you need to do the
>   following:

```
// add a new parameter, with any name we want - its for our own
// use only
SqlParameter sqlParam = com.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
// set the direction flag so that it will be filled with the return value
myParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

> Then, after the stored procedure has
>   been executed,

```
int returnValue = (int)com.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value
```

> will retrieve the value that was set.

Comment: but if use microsoft SQLHelper version 2.0 ?? how can i do that ?

Comment: You might look at @marc_s' answer, maybe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

When adding parameters, there is a "return value" parameter direction:

```
var param = cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter());
param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Inspect the `.Value` of this param after the call (`ExecuteNonQuery`), and you have the return value. One note, though; when using this with `SELECT` results, the return value is only available after **all** the data has been read from the results (return/output is at the **end** of the TDS stream).

Comment: thanks, but if use microsoft SQLHelper version 2.0 ?? how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a parameter with a direction = ReturnValue:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.CheckUsername11", conn) 
            { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@result") { ParameterDirection.ReturnValue });
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

  command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  return (int)command.Parameters["@result"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following URLs it contain the same problem
1- [How to get Return Value of a Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749622/ado-net-how-to-get-return-value-of-a-stored-procedure)
2- [Getting a Return Value in C# asp.net from a stored procedure (syntax issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342806/getting-a-return-value-in-c-asp-net-from-a-stored-procedure-syntax-issue)

Comment: Probably better to leave these as comments.