# Getting return value from the stored procedure

Tags: ado.net

I have written a procedure as following:

```
ALTER PROC ReturnProc
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 5
END
```

I am trying to get the return value from the Procedure in the following way:

```
com.CommandText = "ReturnProc";
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter parameterReturnValue = new SqlParameter();
parameterReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
com.Parameters.Add(parameterReturnValue);

con.Open();
tran = con.BeginTransaction();
com.Transaction = tran;
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
tran.Commit();

//Get the return value
iReturn = Convert.ToInt64(parameterReturnValue.Value);
```

I failed to get the return value after execution. In the real scenario, I am concatenating the parameters with the procedure, rather than adding them in `SqlParameter` list.

Could anybody help me on this?

Comment: I don't know what is happening at your site - it works just fine here, I get the value "5" back (but *why* are you converting that to an `Int64` ??)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to retrieve the value from the Parameters collection. See [How can I get Stored Procedure return value in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123187/how-can-i-get-stored-procedure-return-value-in-c)