# How to check if sproc returns no results

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes in a Department Name and returns the Department Id in the form of an int. I'm trying to use the procedure to determine if a department with the specified name already exists. How can I accomplish this? If the sproc returns no results, what is the value represented by? Is it null? Should I possibly be using a separate sproc to determine if the department already exists? Here is my current sproc:

```
    @Department_Name varchar(100),
    @Id int OUTPUT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT @Id = Id FROM Department
WHERE Name = @Department_Name
    RETURN @Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There are two ways of returning result sets or data from a procedure to a calling program: output parameters and return codes"

[Return Data from a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

[Stored Procedures - Output Parameters & Return Values](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_&_Return_Values)

Answer (score 0):

> Return values can be used within stored procedures to provide the
>   stored procedure execution status to the calling program. The return
>   values -99 through 0 are reserved for SQL Server internal use. You can
>   create your own parameters that can be passed back to the calling
>   program. By default, the successful execution of a stored procedure
>   (or any group of SQL statements) will return 0.

You can return some value to indicate that your **@Id** is null.
And how to get value which you return from SP in ASP you can read here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103538/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t100901-1.shtml
Or you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342862/1048105